# Using dictionary instead of sorting and then searching

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, dictionary

I was studying hash tables and a thought came:

Why not use dictionaries for searching an element instead  of first sorting the list then doing binary search? (assume that I want to search multiple times)

1. We can convert a list to a dictionary in `O(n)` (I think) time because we have to go through all the elements.
2. We add all those elements to dictionary and this takes `O(1)` time
3. When the dictionary is ready,we can then search for any element in  `O(1)` time(average) and `O(n)` is the worst case

Now if we talk about average case `O(n)` is better than other sorting algorithms because at best they take `O(nlogn)`.And if I am right about all of what I have said then why not do this way?

I know there are various other things which you can do with the sorted elements which cannot be done in an unsorted dictionary or array.But if we stick only to search then Is it not a better way to do search than other sorting algorithms?

Comment: Or we just iterate over the unsorted list in O(n) to search the element?

Comment: @timgeb then if you have to do search n times then you have complexity `n*O(n)` and if you sort first and then do search n times it is `n*O(logn)` .And according to john theory you can do search as many times as you want in `O(1)` time which is far better than what you say

Comment: @jamessmith yeah, but you did not mention that you want to search many times. In that case, convert the list to a set (why do you want a dict?) in O(n), then do any subsequent containment check in O(1). Keeping a sorted list you can bisect is only helpful when you need the order and/or duplicate elements.

Comment: @timgeb then why use sorting algorithms for search ? this is a better idea to do that

Comment: @johnsmith who uses sorting algorithms for searching?

Comment: @timgeb you are right but while teaching a class professors often say  that ,searching in better time complexity is what they want to achieve after sorting, thats why I am asking

Comment: When I have an unsorted list and I need to search it many times, I make a map from the list(map is sorted so it can be seen as dictionary). That way I can search the map in O(1) instead of iterating the list. So I think it makes sense.

Comment: I think is is pretty common practice to convert a list to a set (being a special case of a hashmap) for fast repeated lookup. Using a sorted list might be preferrable if you have very little space, as a sparsly-populated hashset would take much more space than the original list (and the denser the hashset is, the more collision you get).

Comment: @timgeb: I do when beneficial for some reason.

Comment: In step 2, what are keys that you use to create dictionary? If you know order of values , sorting the list of those values also takes O(n) time.

Comment: @Vasei its your wish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, a well-designed hash table can beat sorting and searching.

For a proper choice, there are many factors entering into play such as in-place requirement, dynamism of the data set, number of searches vs. insertions/deletions, ease to build an effective hashing function...

Answer (score 1):

*Binary Search* is a searching technique which exploits the fact that list of `key`s in which a `key` is to be searched is already sorted, it doesn't requires you to sort and then search, making its worst case search time `O(log n)`.

If you do not have a sorted list of `key`s and want to search a `key` then you will have to go for linear search which in worst case will run with `O(n)` complexity, there is no need to sort and then search which definitely slower since best known sorting algos can work in only `O(n log n)` time.

Building a `dictionary` from a `list` of `key`s and then performing a lookup is of no advantage here because linear search will yield the same for better performance and also there need for auxiliary memory which would be needed in case of `dictionary`; however *if you have multiple lookups and key space is small* using a `dictionary` can of advantage since building the dictionary is one time work of `O(n)` and subsequent lookups can be done by `O(1)` at the expense of some memory which will be used by the `dictionary`.

Comment: "if you already know the key you are looking for it won't be called searching" - I don't understand this sentence. You are searching for a *presence* of the key you know beforehand. How can you search for something you don't know?

Comment: "best known sorting algos" - it's actually mathematically proven that sorting cannot take less than `O(n log n) + c`. Algorithms today try to minimize that constant `c`.

Comment: "linear search which in worst case will run with O(n) complexity, there is no need to sort and then search which definitely slower since best known sorting algos can work in only `O(n log n)` time." why are you taking that as a case I have said in the question  "(assume that I want to search multiple times)"

Comment: @johnsmith yes if you have multiple search in a fixed list then your technique is definitely better, and its a commonly used approach.